# C# (.NET), Html parse using regex

Tags: c#, html, .net, regex, parsing

Using Regex, I'm trying to get data from html code, but I don't know how build it, without using any html tags.
I have some string (**item-desc**), and count of symbols after this string, which must be my data.
Something like: in **item-desc12345abcde**, I'm using regex with value of 6 symbols, and i got **12345a**.
This expression give me only 1 symbol after my string:

```
Regex itemInfoFilter = new Regex(@"item-desc\s*(.+?)\s*>", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please clarify what you're asking and add relevant samples of data (minimal necessary information to understand your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of your question I think this should work: `item-desc(.){6}(?=[\s'"])`

In the code I assume that your string ends with a `space (\s)`, `'` or `"`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using regular expressions to parse HTML.

Use an HTML parser instead:

[HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)